# Issue with Highcharts spline not correctly positioned

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having a problem with Highcharts spline chart, I'm basically drawing a CPU/RAM chart, getting the values from my NAS API.

This is basically the chart.

[image]

And as you can see, this value is correct (**6**).

[image]

This one is not, **3** is of course lower than **6**, but is displayed higher than **3**.

[image]

And here you can see the **1** value, that is drawn around 24% (The RAM value).

[image]

This is the chart creation:

```
Highcharts.chart({
        title: {
            text: 'CPU and RAM'
        },
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'cpu-memory-chart',
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                shadow: false,
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                animation: 1000
            },
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: '%',
            max: 100,
            min: 0
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 1000,
            labels: {
                /*style: {
                    color: '#aaa'
                }*/
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        colors: ['#4CAF50', '#1F80ED'],
        series: [
            {
                name: "CPU",
                pointInterval: 1000,
                pointStart: (new Date()).getTime()
            },
            {
                name: "RAM",
                pointInterval: 1000,
                pointStart: (new Date()).getTime()
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

And this is how I update points:

(note that *data* is the result of the API call, and *cpuRamSeries* is the serie of the chart)

```
if(points < 10){
                points++;
                cpuRamSeries[0].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), data.cpu]);
                cpuRamSeries[1].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), data.ram]);
            }else{
                cpuRamSeries[0].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), data.cpu], false, true);
                cpuRamSeries[1].addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), data.ram], false, true);
                cpuRamChart.redraw();
            }
```

This is my first try with Highcharts so I don't really know where the problem might be. Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: It is not really clear what your data is, I think [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be handy.

Comment: Could you put the actual data in a variable and do `console.log` on that varaible, then share at least part of it (prefferably the last part where the errors occur). Without that, I would have to say that my guess is that data is aggregated (because of the stacking) and what you see is one of the values that is aggregated.

Comment: Sorry for the missing data, here is what the API sends back:
**{ api: "systemUtilization", cpu: 18, id: 1525778704105, ram:24,success:true}** and **{ api: "systemUtilization", cpu: 1, id: 1525778708218, ram:24,success:true}**, so it looks correct

Comment: I agree with aggregation hypothesis. If you're adding points in the loop, `(Date()).getTime()` will be the same for every point

Comment: Ok, but if I add points to different series, with the same timestamp and different values, do they get aggregated? Can I disable values aggregation?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the aggregation? Also, the `id` passed from the API looks like a timestamp, if it is then that would probably be better to use.

Comment: The problem is that I have never told the chart to aggregate values! I don't want to aggregate values (if that is the problem), I just want to display those two different series in the same chart. Also don't mind the id in the API object, that is used for other purposes, and never passed to the chart

Comment: Ahh okay, well then I would remove `stacking: 'normal',` if I were you.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I probably copied the options from an example on the wiki and didn't notice the stacking property. Thanks